# Take each character in a string and convert it to Hex c++?

Tags: c++, string, hex, user-input, unsigned-char

I am trying to take a user input as a string and convert each individual element into its hex equivalent as an unsigned char in C++. For example I want to take a user input "CL" and convert that into 0x43 and 0x4C stored in an unsigned char.

```
string ui;
unsinged char uihex;

cout << "Please enter in command to execute: ";
cin >> ui;
for (int i=0; i<ui.length()-1; i++)
{
    uihex = static_cast<unsigned char>(ui);
}
```

Comment: Okay, that's a nice beginners assignment. What have you tried so far? What parts do you have problems with? Oh, and stackowerflow.com is not a "give me the codes" site, you need to show some effort yourself.

Comment: You don't need to convert.  The values are the ASCII values for the characters.  Just read in the data.

Comment: I will add what I have tried above.

Comment: Update your post for code.  **DON'T PUT CODE IN COMMENTS**, code belongs in your question.

Comment: I have added the basic code I have tried above. Sorry I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *print* values in hexadecimal, you will need to cast the `char` variable to an integer type.  This will help the compiler choose the correct function for printing:

```
char c = 'C';
cout << "0x" << hex << ((unsigned int) c) << endl;
```

Comment: I am trying to just store the value as a hex so I can pass it through a function.

Comment: Hexadecimal is one interpretation of a variable's *internal representation*, you don't need to convert the representation when passing to functions (exempt string types).  What is the signature of the function you are passing the variable to?

Comment: UARTwrite(bytes_to_write, &uihex), where bytes_to_write is an int and uihex is an unsigned char.

Comment: Use a `static_cast<unsigned char *>(&uihex)` when calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to take a user input as a string and convert each
>   individual element into its hex equivalent as an unsigned char in C++.
>   For example I want to take a user input "CL" and convert that into
>   0x43 and 0x4C stored in an unsigned char.

No conversion is required.

```
char KAR = 'A'; // a char from the file
int  iKAR = static_cast<int>(KAR); // cast to an int
//
std::cout << "\nltr    hex      dec" << std::endl;
std::cout << KAR << "  == "    
          << " 0x" << std::hex     // change to hex radix
          << iKAR                  // hex: KAR cast to an int
          << "  ==  " << std::dec  // change to decimal radix
          << iKAR                  // decimal: KAR cast to an int
          << std::endl;

// output:
// ltr    hex      dec
// A  ==  0x41  ==  65
```